# how to pass data from firebase between tableview cell to view controllers?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase

Hi guys I'm really having troubles trying to pass data from a tableview to another view controller. I have a tableview that displays a list of every user but when I click on a user it goes to the next view controller without showing any data of that particular user. The code below is pretty much the same from an example I followed but for some reason its not working for me. Please help, I've tried searching for solutions but can't find anything. Im also using firebase to store and retrieve my data. Thanks in advance

```
@IBOutlet weak var searchTableView: UITableView!
var profiles = [user]()
var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!

override func viewdidload(){
 databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "guestSegue", sender: self)
    self.searchTableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "guestSegue" {
        if let indexpath = searchTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let guestVC = segue.destination as! guestProfileViewController
            guestVC.ref = profiles[indexpath.row].ref


        }
    }
}
```

user array

```
class User {

var backgroundProfileImage: String!
var fullName: String!
var profilePic: String!
var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
var key: String

init(backgroundProfileImage: String, fullName: String, profilePic: String, key: String = ""){



    self.backgroundProfileImage = backgroundProfileImage
    self.fullName = fullName
    self.profilePic = profilePic
    self.key = key
    self.ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

}

init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot){


    self.backgroundProfileImage = value["backgroundProfileImage"] as! String!
    self.fullName = (snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)["fullName"] as! String
    self.profilePic = (snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)["profilePic"] as! String
    self.uid = (snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)["uid"] as! String!
    self.key = snapshot.key
    self.ref = snapshot.ref

}
```

guestViewController

```
class guestProfileViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var profileImage: UIImage!

    @IBOutlet weak var backgroundProfileImage: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var fullNameLabel: UILabel!

    var ref: FIRDatabaseReference?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    loadProfileData()

    }

func loadProfileData(){

    if let ref = ref {

    ref.observe(.value, with: { (user) in

        let user: User = User(snapshot: user)


                self.fullNameLabel.text = user.fullName

                self.profileImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: user.profilePic), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "default"))

                self.backgroundProfileImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: user.backgroundProfileImage), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "default_1"))
                })


            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: `ref` is being set in viewDidLoad() of guestProfileViewController. Try removing that bit as it seems like you want `ref` to equal the User's `ref`.

Comment: thank you so much! it worked! @PeterTao

Comment: Great! I posted it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ref is being set in viewDidLoad() of guestProfileViewController. Try removing that bit as it seems like you want ref to equal the User's ref.